# Parallely Solve System of Linear equation

Tags: matrix, parallel-processing, linear-algebra

I have a system of linear equation:

```
                        AX = B
             dim(A) = n*n , dim(X) = n*1 , dim(B) = n*1
```

My Scenario :
Suppose I have n different nodes with corresponding row value

```
i.e node 1 = A[1],X[1],B[1]
    node 2 = A[2],X[2],B[2]
    where X is a variable vector to be found.
```

Can anybody suggest an algorithm if possible that converge to the solution?

Constraint: No node can share any information i.e their row value.

without this constraint, Gauss Siedel iterative method was good to go.

Comment: How large is `n`? And why can't the nodes exchange their values? What is the condition number of `A`?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour Consider node as competitive firm that's why Information can't be shared.n can take any value.A is invertible i.e nonsingular.